# не работают slash команды discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу добавить в своего бота слешкоманды, но бот не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо исправить?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from config import settings

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(Bot, sync_commands=True)


@slash.slash(description="Проверка бота")
async def ping(ctx):
    ping = Bot.ws.latency
    emb = discord.Embed(description="Ща сек...", colour=discord.Color.orange())
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Pong! `{ping * 1000:.0f}ms` :ping_pong:', colour=discord.Color.orange())
    await msg.edit(embed=emb)
    print(f'[Logs] На данный момент пинг == {ping * 1000:.0f}ms | ping')

Bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found
```

Другой код, выполняющий эту же функцию выдает такую ошибку:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

Сам код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
from config import settings

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(Bot, sync_commands=True)


@slash.slash(name='hi', description='hi', options=[{"name": "member", "description": "Бот поприветствует вас", "type": 6, "required": True}], guild_ids=[761950725508956160])
@Bot.command(aliase=['hi'])
async def hi(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.send(f'Передаю привет {member.nick}!')

Bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что надо было просто в разделе OAuth2 создать новую ссылку, поставив галочку у значения applications.commands, а потом пригласить бота на сервер по этой ссылке. Работать должны оба кода, приведенных в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

В официальной документации discord написано про рейт лимит в 1 час, для регистрации всех слэш-команд на все доступных серверах, для того чтобы нормально тестить слэш-команды обычно есть параметр `test_guilds`, советую почитать об этом в документации к модулю, который вы используете.